# Switch logo using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using Divi WordPress theme which adds the class `.et-fixed-header` to `#main-header` while scrolling down. In the header there is the logo which I wish to change when there is the class `.et-fixed-header`.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($('#main-header').hasClass( 'et-fixed-header' )) {
         $('#logo').attr('src', 'new-img.png');
    }


});
```

My question is, how to get this to **default logo** when there is no `.et-fixed-header` in the `#main-header`. My code is replacing the logo when I scroll down but it does not go to the default logo when I scroll up or in other words, when there is no such class `.et-fixed-header` in the `#main-header`. I understand I need to place an `else` statement but not sure of the code. Any help will be appreciative.

**Edit**

The logo is uploaded via theme options and not placing manually by the users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the original logo to a js variable and then you'll have it to switch back to when `#main-header` loses it's `.et-fixed-header` class.

```
var origImage = '';
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if($('#logo').attr('src') != 'new-img.png') {
        origImage = $('#logo').attr('src')
    }
    if ($('#main-header').hasClass( 'et-fixed-header' )) {
        $('#logo').attr('src', 'new-img.png');
    }
    else {
        $('#logo').attr('src', origImage);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. I just updated the question. The default logo is uploaded via theme options and not being placed manually in the jQuery code

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out and update the question. Once again thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I will do some more customization and then it's done.